# BufferedReader ignoring \r\n when reading html page?

Tags: java, php, html, bufferedreader, plaintext

I'm using Apache HTTPClient to send a POST request to a page, I then read the response using a BufferedReader.

For some reason BufferedReader is reading the two lines I respond with as 1 line. My response:

```
SUCCESS  
RANDOM STRING
```

Here is my PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo 'SUCCESS';
echo '\\r\\n';
echo 'Random String';
```

Buffered Reader just prints out

```
success\r\nRandom String
```

Am I doing something wrong? I used the normal br.readLine() with a loop to read everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues:

- Escape sequences must be in double quotes, not single quotes. In single quotes, PHP doesn't look for escape sequences except for `\'` and `\\`.
- You're escaping the backslashes themselves, which causes PHP to echo literal backslashes. A single backslash is all you need.

Just replace

```
echo '\\r\\n';
```

with

```
echo "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They won't be interpreted as new line characters when they're in single quotes. They'll be interpreted literally as `\r\n`. Use double quotes instead.

```
echo "\r\n";
```

Escape sequences are only valid in double quotes.